# Join the associated object into the belongs_to object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have an `Event` model which *has many* `DateEntry` because an event can have multiple *datetimes*.

I have a view where I see all the events with date entries for a specific day. For which I've made this class method in **models/event.rb**:

```
def self.by_date(date)
  includes(:date_entries)
  .where(date_entries: { begins_at: date.beginning_of_day..date.end_of_day })
end
```

And it works fine.

Now on the view I loop over the events I grabbed with that query:

```
@events.each do |event|
  # whatever
```

I am looking for a way to use the date from the selected DateEntry in the loop. I think I have to use ActiveRecords `joins` method, but I have tried in many ways and when I am not getting an error the output is still the same.

For clarifying, I want to do in the loop something like `event.selected_date_entry_by_the_by_date_method.begins_at` or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in your example the date for all events will be the same. You could easily set `@date` in your controller and then use that in the views.

Second, It seems like you should be doing things the other way around. Instead of finding the Events you should be finding DateEntries and iterating over those.

Comment: The date isn't always the same, because I have in my controller `@events = Event.by_date Date.today`, which calls that class method.
I thought it would be a cleaner way to loop over the events instead of the date entries. But if everything else fails I think I will doing it so in the end.

Comment: I am finally looping over the date entries. Couldn't find any other way.

Answer (score 0):

Your method `Event.by_date` used `includes` so it eager loads the `date_entries` for the events you need. It automatically does a join. In the loop just do

```
@events.each do |event|
  data_entries = event.date_entries
  # do something with the dates...
end
```

Your `Event` model should have `has_many :date_entries`.

The `date_entries` call will return all the dates for that event and won't result in another query.

Run this in the rails console and you will see the queries being run.

Comment: `event.date_entries` grabs all the date_entries related to the event. But I think that's normal, since it is the expected behaviour in rails with models associations.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way, but i suggest to do it as followng, this class method should be a scope or even class method but in DateEntry model:

```
class DateEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :by_date,->(date){ where(...)}
end

@events.each do |event|
 event.date_entries.by_date(date).each do |date_entry|
      # .....
 end
 # .....
end
```

Comment: Thank you. This works but it doesn't attach the given date entry to the actual event. It binds all date entries within the scope to the event. I don't want to loop over date entries, I want to loop over the events and find the date entry associated with the first query.

Comment: Ok, what i understand from you that you want the first result so you can replace the loop with: event.date_entries.by_date(date).limit(1).first.try(:begins_at)  and i used here "try" because may be there is no any entry date so try will prevent  exception from raise

Comment: You should _not_ perform queries inside an iterator like this because it results in N + 1 queries to the database.

Comment: its not shouldn't but its not effecient for time consuming, and no one said its the effecient solution but it solving the problem here, votes for solving the problems here!

Comment: But if I have an event on the same day with two different date entries, it will always get the first one. With the first query I ment the one I use in my class method.